Export AWS AMI to GCP
How much limit to export AMI from AWS to GCP.
When I trying to export AMI from AWS to GCP it's showing
failed to begin export AWS image: ResourceCountExceeded: You already reached the maximum limit (1) of active export image tasks  status code: 400,
I want to know limit of exporting images.
